# Testing SQS,Lambda integration locally with large number of messages

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

What is the best way to simulate having around 100 messages in AWS SQS using Java.
My goal is to test lambda and DLQ functionality when there are around 100 messages in my Queue,to see how throttling and failures work.

Answer (score 1):

Write an interface exposing methods needed to get the messages and properly handle them and write the code that needs to consume messages using that interface.

```
interface SqsService {
    List<Message> getMessages();
    void deleteMessage(Message message);
}
```

Then create one implementation using the AWS SDK. You will use that under normal conditions.

```
class SqsMessageService implements MessageService {

    private String queueUrl;

    @Override
    List<Message> getMessages() {
        return sqs.receiveMessage(queueUrl).getMessages();
    }

    @Override
    void deleteMessage(Message message) {
        sqs.deleteMessage(queueUrl, message.getReceiptHandle());
    }
}
```

Then write another implementation that doesn't talk to AWS but instead returns a number of messages.

```
class FakeMessageService implements MessageService {
    
    @Override
    List<Message> getMessages() {
        final List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        ...code to generate 100 messages...
        return messages;
    }

    @Override
    void deleteMessage(Message message) {
        return;
    }
}
```

This way you can easily switch between your implementations without changing a lot of code. Also I assume you don't want to actually send 100 or more SQS messages since that is an obvious answer but you would have to (probably) pay for that. And you don't really need it if you want to benchmark the other part of your app and how it integrates with AWS.